# Can PCI device address CPU PA directly if IOMMU (intel VT-D) is disabled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pci

My understanding is that if a PCI device want to do DMA RW, and IOMMU is enabled, the driver should map CPU PA into a DMA address via pci_map_page(for non-coherent), then PCI device can use this DMA address and IOMMU will translate the DMA address into CPU PA.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible for driver to disable IOMMU for a given device?
2. If someone disable IOMMU via bios, does it mean any CPU PA can be directly DMA RW?

Answer (score 1):

1. The VT-d hardware allows setting pass-through separately for each device, but Linux does not currently provide a driver API to do it.
2. Yes, DMA from PCI/PCIe devices uses system physical addresses when the IOMMU is disabled, either in the BIOS or by using intel_iommu=off in the Linux command line.

Comment: @pri if you want to pass-through a generic pci device, you can use `vfio` driver. `vfio` driver will expose IOMMU mapped address of the hardware to userspace.

Comment: @prl regarding 2nd question, is your answer is that w/o IOMMU, today intel CPU can allow PCI use CPU PA for DMA RW?